# xpath selecting elements and iterating over the tag

Tags: python, xpath, hyperlink, extract

Consider the

tag in my html is like this

```
<div class ="summary">
    <p>Best <a class="abch" href="/canvas">canvas</a> abcdefgh <a class="zph" href="/canvas">canvas</a>, I cycle them to garden</p>
</div>
```

When I do

```
site.select('.//*[contains(@class, "summary")]/p/text()').extract()
```

I get only the text of p and the hyperlinks are lost.
I want to do extract the data of

as well as the textual data of  (eg canvas above). There can be any number of  tags inside the

element. they may or may not be present within the

tag.

Any idea how to extract the entire data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two slashes after `p` will work for you. One slash `/` selects children only, two slashes `//` will include deeper elements. Since text nodes under `a` are not direct children of `p` they are not selected.

```
site.select('.//*[contains(@class, "summary")]/p//text()').extract()
```

Update:

Answering to your comment: I can only can think of such way:

```
for p in site.select('.//*[contains(@class, "summary")]/p'):
    p.select('//text()').extract()
```

Comment: Well, there are many summary tags inside the html document. So if I d a p//, it would return the text of all those summary tags. Whereas I want the description to be fetched for one tag at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**When this XPath expression is evaluated**:

```
string(.//*[contains(@class, "summary")]/p)
```

**the result is a string that is the concatenation (in document order) of all of the text nodes descendants of** `p`.

I guess that this is what you want.

Comment: this would return all the text with the tags!

Comment: @Gaurav: The statement in your comment is completely wrong -- just try to see what the result is! And read and learn! Never make absolute statements about things you don't know.